# Aperture Jitter in Digital to Analog Converters

Tags: digital-communications, sampling, analog-to-digital, digital-to-analog

I have noticed in the literature that there is an internally induced timing jitter inside Analog to digital converters called (aperture jitter). It is caused by the sample-and-hold circuit of the ADC.
So what about the digital to analog converter? does it contain a sample-and-hold circuit? does it induce aperture jitter?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes absolutely there is also the equivalent of aperture jitter results in a DAC. This is due to the effects of jitter in the sampling clock itself, and variation in the electronics of the time duration for the translation from the different digital levels to analog levels in the output.

In either case the jitter is not necessarily just due to a S/H circuit but the combined effects of that interface as well as the clock itself, and power supply noise can also translate to aperture jitter given the resulant changes in threshold levels.

Comment: thanks for your great efforts